# php - session seems as like it was never removed, even after using session remove + forget+put null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

in my code,
after saving changes in the project
im suppose to clearing the employeNo session
after using a lot of method to make sure the session is cleared
and checking that it is indeed clear
im refreshing the page and it seems the session was not even cleared
(look like it put the employee number again in the session some how)
because i checked and before the refresh the session indeed was empty

VERY IMPORTANT:
this things only happening once in a while,
for example - in general the process is working well
**but sometimes randomlly it happens**

tried a lot: (this is from an function that is called by using ajax, POST)
this part is in the end of the function before finishing it and then refreshing the page on
ajax success part
(i also tried to put the refresh in the complete section)

```
    Log::info('clear');
    Log::info(session()->get('pick.employeeNoGD'));

    while (session()->get('pick.employeeNoGD')) {
        session()->put('pick.employeeNoGD', null);
        session()->forget('pick.employeeNoGD');            
        session()->remove('pick.employeeNoGD');            
    }
    session()->put('pick.employeeNoGD', null);
    session()->forget('pick.employeeNoGD');
    session()->remove('pick.employeeNoGD');
    sleep(2);

    Log::info('after - clear');
    Log::info(session()->get('pick.employeeNoGD'));
    Log::info('end - clear');
```

and still some how after refreshing the page, it seems that the session was not cleared

when i checked what happens using the logs,
it seems that the session indeed was clear

ty for help :D

Comment: Not sure about the issue but I would suggest to use Session Facade. syntax is slightly different but the result is the same. As for your problem, check if there are parts of the code where you are still adding the session too

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth - _"I would suggest to use Session Facade"_ - Could you elaborate on why? As far as I know, they will use the same session instance behind the scenes anyway.

Comment: If you send a request then your code should be like this: $request->session()->forget('pick.employeeNoGD'); but if not you should use Session::forget('pick.employeeNoGD');